# How to call Task in NavigationLink destination in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I've created a list using `LazyVStack` and inside of the list there are `ListItemView`s.

What I'm trying to do is, when a `ListItemView` gets tapped, I want to make an async call depending on the selected item, and then navigate to the view with the data I fetched.

I've tried to do so by placing a `Task` inside of `destination` parameter of `NavigationLink` but I think this is not permissible. I get `Type '() -> Task<some View, Never>' cannot conform to 'View'` error.

Here is the list that I'm implementing

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                Task {
                    await detailView(from: item.id) // <- Type '() -> Task<some View, Never>' cannot conform to 'View'
                }
            }, label: {
                ListItemView(item: item)
            })
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
        } //: ForEach
    } //: LazyVStack
} //: ScrollView
```

And here is the method that I use to generate destination view.

```swift
private func detailView(from id: Int) async -> some View {
    guard let product = await viewModel.getProduct(with: id) else { return Text("Error").eraseToAnyView() }
    selectedProduct = product
    return ProductDetailView(product: $selectedProduct).eraseToAnyView()
}
```

Any ideas how can I implement this?

Comment: You can't asynchronously return a `View`. You should pass the `item` to the view and have the view start the data retrieval.  The view should show placeholder data until the data fetch is complete.

Comment: @Paulw11 it's possible to achieve this effect, see my answer below.

Comment: It's possible, but pretty awful

Comment: @Paulw11 The whole SwiftUI is awful imo. Many stuff I consider basic with UIKit require jumping though hoops to achieve in SwiftUI. But, it's getting better.

Comment: Not really. You just have to separate your view from your model properly. If you try and write procedural code in your view you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Paulw11 well, of course. But I’m talking about the UI part, it’s buggy, glitchy, and often hacky.

Comment: OP see my answer. If it answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows.
You will have to use a button to call the Task, which will update a `@State` var `loadedText` when done, and then activate the `NavigationLink`.

It seems the only way to achieve what you're looking for.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDetailViewActive = false
    @State private var loadedText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button("Show Detail View") {
                    Task {
                        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                        loadedText = "HELLO"
                        isDetailViewActive = true
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(text: loadedText),
                    isActive: $isDetailViewActive
                ) {
                    Text("").hidden()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View - \(text)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your NavigationLink suggestion is deprecated for iOS 16.0+